# What's the benefit of Upcounting or Downcounting or Center-aligned mode of timer/counter?

Tags: timer, counter

I have done several project (3-4 project) via Timers/Counters but I'm curious to know Why do they have three mode for counting?

[image: figure1]

Also I know that in Upcounting mode it count from zero to 0xff... or in Downcounting mode it count from 0xff... to zero and so on for center-aligned as you can see.

What was your experience to use these three mode?

What is the advantage and disadvantage of each mode?

Comment: Center aligned can be used to generate phase correct PWM (better symmetry).

Comment: @jippie Oh, Can be used to generate asymmetrical PWMs or symmetry PWM? look at Mishyoshi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application!  Up counting is the most common when counting intervals.  Down-counting is much more practical when performing count downs before an event occurs, because you start from where your want down to zero instead of offsetting your trigger relative to your current count or both reset timer and trigger to desired interval.

I personally never used the center aligned mode, but based on a [STM App note (DM00042534)](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00042534.pdf), it can be used to generate asymmetrical PWMs with a given phase shift...

Answer (score 1):

Benefit of "Center-aligned mode" is thoroughly explained (called "double-edge PWM") in The Book :

"The significant feature of double-edge naturally sampled PWM is that the odd harmonic sideband components around odd multiples of the carrier fundamental, and even harmonic sideband components around even multiples of the carrier fundamental, are completely eliminated. This is an intrinsic advantage of double-edge naturally sampled modulation using a triangular carrier compared to single-edge modulation using a sawtooth carrier."

G. Holmes,‎ T. Lipo “Pulse Width Modulation for Power Converters” Wiley-IEEE Press; 2003.